# A featured post above then below another loop will exclude the featured post

Tags: wordpress

Hi Im trying to do some stuff on wordpress, 
my question is how can I exclude the featured post in another wordpress loop

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First step: create a category for the post(s) you want to be featured.

Step two: [exclude that category from the loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop), like so (in the code below, category 3 and category 8 are both being excluded):

```
<?php query_posts($query_string . '&cat=-3,-8'); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<div class="post">

<!-- Display the Title as a link to the Post's permalink. -->
<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

<!-- Display the date (November 16th, 2009 format) and a link to other posts by this posts author. -->
<small><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> by <?php the_author_posts_link() ?></small>

<div class="entry">
<?php the_content(); ?>
</div>

<p class="postmetadata">Posted in <?php the_category(', '); ?></p>
</div> <!-- closes the first div box -->

<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```